# Turbo Size for 360 Mopar

Tags: dodge, turbocharger

I have a 360 mopar that I recently bought that has been modified a good bit by the previous owner. It's got iron heads, running about 9.5 to 1 compression. Was told it has been bored and stroked to a 408. It also has been "cammed" but I have no numbers on that unfortunately.

I would love to through a turbo on it and get as close to 600 hp as possible. I would like to stay under 12psi to minimize exploding the engine. Car will mostly be used for weekend drives and may go to the strip occasionally. What turbo size/make would work best for this application?
I have had a s475 recommended in the past but am unsure if this would be a good match.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually looking at it wrong in how do you apply a turbocharger and make power. You can't say, "would like to stay under 12psi" and find a turbo, because the engine will take what it will take (psi wise) to make 600hp. Any given turbo has a potential to produce a given HP number on whichever engine it is installed on. This is because any given turbo will only flow so much air, which means it will produce only so much HP.

It doesn't matter what *type* of engine you put it on, it can only produce that maximum amount of HP. Depending on what kind of engine it is, how well the heads flow, how much cam is in it, and what type of exhaust is used, will dictate how much boost will be required to get you to whatever power level you are trying to achieve.

Something to think about is that to figure out the approximate boost level you'll need to run to achieve a number is to realize that "basically" it takes one atmosphere of boost (~15psi) to double the HP of any given engine. If your engine, right now, is producing 400hp, you'll need ~7.5psi of boost to get to that magic 600hp number. When you start throwing power numbers around, it's a good idea to know where you are starting from to understand what you need to do to get to the point of where you want to be.

The suggestion of the Borg Warner S475 with a T4 flange is not a bad suggestion if you only want 600hp. [Richard Holdner put a single S475 on his 6.0L "Big Bang" engine](https://www.motortrend.com/how-to/borg-warner-turbo-shootout-size-matters/) and was able to produce produced 878 hp and 804 lb-ft of torque at a peak boost pressure of just 11.3 psi on an engine dyno. This was basically a stock LS engine with the only real modification being gapping the top rings to accommodate the hotter temps produced when running forced induction. If you figure that was on the engine dyno, it should be right in your neck of the woods of ~600hp on a chassis dyno (maybe a bit more). What it tells me is, the S475 is probably a good choice for what you're saying. The big downfall of it is, that's pretty much maxed out. If you EVER want to go higher in the HP range, you're going to need a bigger turbocharger. More than likely with your larger displacement engine, you'd be able to produce those numbers on less boost and most likely at a lower RPM range then he did.

To help with your decision, I believe most manufacturers produce a list of the approximate level of HP output any given turbo will make. For instance, [here is a list of turbo offerings from Borg-Warner](https://www.borgwarner.com/docs/default-source/iam/boosting-technologies/efr-power-range.pdf) which ranges from 350 up to 1100hp per turbocharger. You'll have to figure out exactly how to read that PDF, however, you can tell by it through mixing different housings and turbine assemblies, you can have different styles and outputs from the turbos.